# Multi auth on laravel using the same login page

Tags: laravel

I'm working on a project where I have Admin and Employee, I want the two of this user to login using one login form provided by laravel. This two users have a separate table.

This is the guard I define;

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'employee' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'employees',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],


 'providers' => [
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],

    'employees' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Employee::class,
    ],

],
```

And I Overwrite `attemptLogin` in `LoginController`

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request){
$customerAttempt = Auth::guard('employee')->attempt(
    $this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember')
);
if(!$customerAttempt){
    return Auth::guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember')
    );
} 
return $customerAttempt;


}
```

But is not working...I can't login with the employee user, it always return `null` when I `dd(Auth::user());`

Comment: Did your run `php artisan config:cache`?

Comment: Yes,  even composer dumpautoload